# Form method get not working

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I don't know why my form get won't work, here is my code:
adding words because can't post edit..............................................
P.S **all other piece of code works perfect!!!**

Page: 1:

```
<button id="Head" onclick="rollHead()">Head</button>
<button id="Tail" onclick="rollTail()">Tail</button>

<script>
function rollTail(){
    var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    if(d1 == 1)
    {
    die1.innerHTML = "You won!";
    fliped.innerHTML = "Fliped Tail!";
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST','won.php',true);
    ajax.send();
    }
    else if (d1 == 2)
    {
    die1.innerHTML = "You lose!";
    fliped.innerHTML = "Fliped Head!";
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST','lose.php',true);
    ajax.send();
    }
}
function rollHead(){
    var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    if(d1 == 1)
    {
    die1.innerHTML = "You lose!";
    fliped.innerHTML = "Fliped Tail!";
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST','lose.php',true);
    ajax.send();
    }
    else if (d1 == 2)
    {
    //alert(document.getElementById('wonorlose').value );
    die1.innerHTML = "You won!";
    fliped.innerHTML = "Fliped Head!";
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST','won.php',true);
    ajax.send();
    }
}
</script>

<form method="get" action="won.php">
<h2 align="center">
<input type="text" name="wonorlose" value=50>
</h2>
</form>
```

Page: won.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: /manopuslapis/index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$wonorlose = $_GET["wonorlose"];
echo $wonorlose;
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET credits=credits+'$wonorlose' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']); 
?>
```

Comment: You can update your code how it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem in `won.php` at this line

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
```

You have `$_SESSION['user']` as string.. This must be integer **OR** you must add quotes:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
```

Or define `$_SESSION["user"]` as integer by adding `(int)` after `=` where you define it.

**UPDATE**

Problem solved with teamviewer. User got blank variable `$wonorlose` because he make AJAX POST without parameters. I changet AJAX POST into AJAX GET with parameter `wonorlose` and now its working. Final code have only author.